# Is it good in Rails view to define constant just to be used once?

Tags: ruby

To a partial in a HAML file, I am passing parameters whose value is long, or methods whose name is long, for example:

- `"Some quite long string"`
- `quiteLongMethodNameHere(otherConstant)`

To make them shorter, I wrapped them in a constant/variable:

```
- message = "Some quite long string"
- is_important = quiteLongMethodNameHere(otherConstant)

= render :some_component, msg: message, is_important: is_important
```

Is this a good practice? Or should I just put the value on the `param` without wrapping it inside variable/constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a case-by-case decision. You want to balance the sometimes-competing interests of clarity and conciseness. For me, it depends on the expressiveness of both forms. If the long method name is clear, precise, and expressive, then I would be less interested in using an intermediate variable to hold its result than if it were not.

In other cases where the long form is less expressive, I will often use intermediate variables as "living" documentation, even if they are used only on the next line of code. This more explicitly reveals your intention to the reader (who may someone else, or you at some future point in time).
I find intermediate variables are much better than code comments because code comments can more easily become obsolete, and having the clarification in code makes it available for debuggers, etc. The performance hit of creating an extra variable is minimal, and significant in only the most unusual of cases.

Another factor is if you are aggregating things (in arrays, hashes, etc.) that include these function calls and values, then using the intermediate variable makes the code neater, and possibly easier to understand, as you can customize the name to make the most sense in the context of that collection.

Comment: thanks for the insight. in ruby on rails, is there some low level optimisation like in C where the compiler translate a=1; print(a); ---> print(1) ?

Comment: Excellent question. As far as I know, no, but the Ruby core team has been working on some dramatic optimizations, and it wouldn't surprise me if they are addressing this. If you use JRuby, Ruby on the JVM, the Java runtime does some runtime optimization, but I'm not sure if that extends as far as running Ruby code.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the length of the string, it makes sense to assign it to a variable/constant, and not directly refer to it in a view file. If it is a text, it makes more sense to put it in a i18n file.

However, it is not good to do that in the main view file. If you are going to do it, do it in the controller file or a helper file.